# How to accès iboutlet from another class in swift

Tags: swift, iboutlet

so I want to change the button colour from view controller but the problem is my button referencing to my collection view class. I dunno how to call the button from another class

collection view

```
class CollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var menusButton: UIButton!

public func MenuButtonFunction (){
menusButton.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 1.0, green: 1.0, blue: 1.0, alpha: 1.0)
}
```

Viewcontroller

```
var menuButtonFunc = CollectionViewCell()
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
menuButtonFunc.MenuButtonFunction()

     doneButton.layer.cornerRadius = 10

}
```

Comment: Create a public function in the receiving class (that owns the button) that modifies the button internally and then call this function from your other class

Comment: the result is nil

Comment: Are you kidding me? The result of what, how are we supposed to know what you mean? Please read about [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and update your question.

Comment: sorry.. I'm new in swift, I already share my code but the result is error when unwrap the value

Comment: Your class is not a view, it's a cell. That cell belongs to a view class and that view class and that view is handled by a view controller class I assume and that is how you need to access the button, `-> view controller -> view -> cell -> button`.

Answer (score 1):

My first instinct would be to use [delegation](https://www.swiftbysundell.com/posts/delegation-in-swift) or the [observer](https://www.swiftbysundell.com/posts/observers-in-swift-part-1) pattern.

I can't say much more without knowing more detail of your code (i.e. if it really is simple, view-hierarchy-wise, then [Joakim Danielson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9223839/joakim-danielson)'s comment of just using a public function is probably your best solution).

Comment: how to call the function ? my result is nil when call the function

Answer (score 0):

You should not instantiate your cell with constructor call - it will not create child items and that is the reason why you have `nil` reference on your button. You should call [dequeueReusableCell](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionview/1618063-dequeuereusablecell) UICollectionView method to obtain fully created cell.